# Setting Backbone Marionette model via Global Object

Tags: javascript, rest, web-applications, backbone.js, marionette

In a [Backbone.Marionette](http://marionettejs.com/) application I'm building, we have an authentication which returns a `user` object, which we in turn stash at `App.User` (so it's not truly global).

The problem I'm having is that I don't want to make a call to an API endpoint to access the various properties of the returned `user` object.  The specific use case I'm working through right now is that the returned `user` object contains data about which modules in the app the user is permitted to access (no worries about security, we've clarified that it's OK that the user can spoof a var in their console to gain access to the UI, the services layer will prevent their actions in such an area from being meaningful).

My goal is to avoid a scenario where every time I need access to `users.appAccess` (a hypothetical array that lists the modules I can access) in order to instantiate it as a model I have to call out to a URL / API endpoint by declaring it in the collection's definition like this:

```
    Entities.Access = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        url: 'http://example.com/users/:id/access/',
        }
    });
```

Removing the `url` property from the above code throws an error, and I can pass it a function which returns empty but this doesn't play nice with

```
   var access = new Entities.Access() 
   access.fetch();
```

when attempting to pass the fetched collection to a Marionette CollectionView.  Should I simply avoid using the `fetch()` method and keep it otherwise a typical (albeit hack-ish) Backbone collection definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backbone allows you to populate a Backbone collection either as you have (with an empty constructor) or with a collection of data. It sounds like you've already got the data stored in the User object, and you want to push this information to the `Entities.Access` collection.

```
var access = new Entities.Access(user.access);
```

I'm with you, this feels a bit like a hack, but since Backbone doesn't support this nativly there isn't much else you can do. Have a look at [Backbone-Relational](https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational) or [supermodel.js](http://pathable.github.com/supermodel/). These projects provide better forms of model nesting than the default implementation.